# How does golang embed .dll, .dylib, .so into products?

Tags: go, embed, cgo

I'm trying to write a Go module for a C++ OCR library, and it's going very well, but I'm running into two problems with the followup.

1. when building a product using go build, the product has to be deployed together with the OCR library in order to run properly, how can I embed the OCR library (.dll, .dylib, .so files) directly into the product?
2. after other developers use go get to import my Go module, need to manually configure the OCR library, how do I configure for other developers to automatically compile and install the OCR library?

I refer to Golang's SQLite3, but unfortunately I found that it is a direct reimplementation of SQLite using go.

I also tried to use embed, but the result is that cgo can't read it correctly.

I'd like to be able to embed these bits and pieces to save other developers and users the trouble of having to manually install and configure OCR libraries.